# Different views on storyboard and in execution (old project)

Tags: xcode, storyboard

We try to create a new project at Xcode. We create it and put some buttons on View on storyboard. When we execute project it executes an old project. What Im thinking is in Java there is a thing like set as main project is there anything like this in Xcode? Moreover if not what might cause the problem of this. It shows different buttons in storyboard and in execution it opens old project :S. I didn't like Xcode to be honest but I have to :(

Comment: Try to clean the project. Build->Clean

Comment: Thats what I wonder but it didnt help the solution it opens old project !! Why??

Comment: Moreover it doesnt work just as a UI it seems the same (Different from the ones in storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Your project will have a file called -Info.plist. If you open this you will find and entry with the name of the main storyboard. This should be the storyboard you are editing. If it is something else that would explain the behaviour you describe.